# Where to modify translation files by _e()

Tags: multi-language, localization

I am in a rush right now and can't seem to find the answer i"m looking for.

I have a wordpress website that has english and french versions.  I see it is using Multi site language switcher to flip between the different sites.

WHen i look in the template files, i see the `_e('some text in here')` function which is responsible for rendering english and french text .

However, I can't seem to locate the language/localization files.  I went into wp-content/language and I see .mo and .po files.  The .mo file is not human readable and hte .po file doesn't have the dictionary of words I want to modify.

Can someone tell me what I need to do to update the localization files?

Comment: First of all read this http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress and try this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/

Answer (score 2):

Themes have their own language files. Look in your themes folder for a po file: /wp-content/themes/yourtheme/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of in "wp-content", the .mo & .po files should be present in the particular theme/plugin directory, in which the php file was present. Please check that directory.

Basically .mo file is a compiled version of .po file. So to update the localized text, you'll first edit the .po file & then compile it(which generates the .mo file) & wordpress would read from the .mo file